# how to get time period between two dates

Tags: php, date, date-math

I have two dates and i want to get the amount of time between them.
I try this:

```
$created_dt="2014-01-30 09:27:02";    
$done_dt="2014-01-30 16:29:38";

$created_dt=strtotime($created_dt); //1391066822
$done_dt=strtotime($done_dt); //1391092178
$runing_time= $created_dt-$done_dt; //25356
$runing_time= date('H:i',$runing_time);
echo $runing_time; //  "09:02" <----------???????
```

why is $runing_time = 09:02 ???

what is a good way around this?
thanks

Part 2
how can i sum a few $intervals together? and after that get their average?
I try:

```
   $average_time;
   foreach($tasks as $task)
   {

   $date1 = new DateTime($task['start']);
   $date2 = new DateTime($task['end']);
   $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
   $runing_time=$interval->format("%h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
   $average_time+=$interval ;
   }
   $final_average_time=average_time/4;
```

obviously my code didnt work because $interval is a an object.

Comment: Please use the php function date_diff() http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: what data base are you working with, mysql?

Comment: Because you are asking it at what hour and minute it was in your timezone on unix timestamp `25356`, which has little to do with the difference in seconds between the to times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, you better use `DateTime()`, but no one here is talking about your issue and why are you getting the wrong result .

Its because `date()` function get 2nd parameter  as time stamp and returns the date : `1970-1-1 00:00:00 GMT` **+** `given time stamp` , pay attention to **GMT** part. 
it means if your time zone is **+2**, then `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",0)` returns `1970-1-1 2:00:00` , **not** `1970-1-1 00:00:00`.

So, the result that you are getting, is `07:02`(real different) **+** `2 hours`(your time zone) . if you insist of getting the result using `date()`, you must change the last lines to:

```
$runing_time= $done_dt - $created_dt - 2*3600;
$runing_time= date('H:i',$runing_time); 
//returns 07:02
```

Comment: @user2706762 1.it is another question , 2.you didn't response to any of answers

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for date math. *Much* easier to do.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2014-01-30 09:27:02");
$date2 = new DateTime("2014-01-30 16:29:38");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->format("%h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OffdS2)

Comment: @user2706762 That needs to be its own separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) , the `diff` method returns the difference between two DateTime objects

```
$createDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $created_dt);
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $done_dt);
$interval = $createDate->diff($endDate2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days %H hours %i Minutes and %s Seconds');
```

Comment: `createFromFormat()` is unnecessary as MySQL datetime format is easily parsed by `DateTime()`

Comment: @John Conde if the format is of MYSQL datetime avoiding the createFromFormat would be faster ?

Comment: I don't know if there is a difference in speed. But if there is it probably is so small that it really doesn't matter. But it is simpler to avoid using createFromFormat() when it isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks @John Conde. I will keep that in mind in future.